# Переключение раскладки клавиатуры в Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, клавиатура, gnome

После обновления до Ubuntu 17.10 перестала работать переключение раскладки по сочетании клавиш <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.
Более менее работает на <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>, но не везде.
При логине приходится пользоваться переключение мышкой.
Как исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Столкнулся с аналогичной ситуацией, стандартное изменение раскладки не помогло. Выручила утилита **gnome-tweak-tool**. 
Раздел **Keyboard&Mouse** >> **Keyboard** >> **Additional Layout Option** >> **Switching to another layout**, далее выбираете нужные сочетания.

Comment: Кстати, советую в этой тулзе выставить переключение раскладки капс локом. При этом оригинальный функционал капс лока будет работать с зажатым шифтом. Очень удобно, как по мне!