# Как в Ubuntu 18 настроить переключение раскладки на Ctrl+Shift?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, клавиатура, gnome

В настройках горячих клавиш невозможно поменять на горячую клавишу ни <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> ни на <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Также в [интернете](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736994/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B2-ubuntu-17-10) широко обсуждается решение использовать GNOME Tweaker, но его проблема в том, что перестают работать комбинации клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Any</kbd>.

Comment: Да есть такая проблема, причем началась она как только на Gnome мигрировать начали (даже не знаю, связано оно с этим как-то или нет). Версию ядер меняли после установки? Бывает что с этим связано. Я решил у себя эту проблему именно обновлением ядра (на форуме подсказали и в моем случае это помогло решить проблему). Правда иногда эти обновы только вредят (((

Comment: Нет, ядро не менял. Проблема решилась полностью? До какой версии ядра обновляли?

Comment: @VladSpirin Лезть в ядро за сменой раскладки как то не серьёзно. Можно ведь просто принять что это другая система - не винда, не мак... дефолнтный **Win** + **Space** уже лет 6 стоит не тревожит, одновременно приходится работать на винде и маке, и там свои сочетания.

Comment: @МаксимАнархистов проблема была еще в 17.10 далее как-раз пришло обновление обновился до 18.04 далее проблема осталась. Честно, номерацию ядра не помню уже, обновлял где-то в мае до самого нового, там глянь какие были доступны в то время.

Comment: @Hellseher я знаю, и с ядром сам не сторонник манипуляции разные делать. Но на тот момент все перепробывал и другого выхода не нашел. Пользователей у данного ПК несколько и не все могут мириться с неудобствами, пришлось решать проблему. В целом согласен с такой точкой зрения, косяки неизбежны в любой ОС. Я на Ubuntu c 10.04 (постоянно только на ней из ОС на ядре Linux с 12.04) так что свыкся уже с такими моментами )))

Comment: @МаксимАнархистов [глянте сюда](https://compizomania.blogspot.com/2013/10/ubuntu-1310_18.html), там решение еще правда по версии 13.10, но может поможет. Да и вообще может найдете там свой ответ. Чем смог, тем помог.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась командами:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nrbrtx/xorg-hotkeys
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

А после настройкой через GNOME Tweaks (ссылка подробную настройку есть в самом вопросе)

Таким образом становится возможно и переключать раскладку любыми комбинациями и использовать раскладки клавиш в которых присутствует комбинация переключения раскладки.

UPD: Проблема не решается до конца - при использовании комбинации клавиш внутри которых есть клавиши переключения раскладки и переключается язык и включается хоткей. А должно быть только второе

Comment: Да, друзья, я как автор этого PPA (но не патча, за патч спасибо Kyak из [ArchLinux](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xorg-server-bug865/)) могу подтвердить, что в GNOME даже после патча будет дополнительная функциональность (почему? - спросите у разработчиков GNOME). Мой наиболее обширный пост на эту тему есть на [AskUbuntu про `<Ctrl+Shift>`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029605/66509), можете посетить опрос по ссылке внизу ответа для предоставления большей статистики. Проблемы нет после установки пакетов из моего PPA в 16.04 LTS с HWE (Unity, MATE, Xfce); 18.04 LTS (Cinnamon, KDE, MATE, Xfce).

Comment: N0rbert А как быть с проблемой, описанной в UPD?

Comment: Я долго мучился этой проблемой, в итоге перешел на переключение языка через <CapsLock>. Привык за месяц.

Comment: @МаксимАнархистов забить на этот новый чудесный прекрасный GNOME и использовать нормальный стол - Unity, MATE, Xfce, KDE, Cinnamon (возможно и еще какие-нибудь, но я их не тестировал). В них патч применяется как нужно (без конфликта с сочетаниями клавиш и без переключения языка когда не нужно). Я остановился на [MATE](http://ubuntu-mate.org/). Мне нужно просто комфортно работать, а бороться с глюками и урезанием функциональности GNOME я устал!

Comment: @N0rbert в Unity на 18.04 патч к сожалению не помог. Есть какие-нибудь апдейты как это исправить на Unity?

Comment: @Modder Давайте уточним значение переменной текущего рабочего стола (`echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`). Если она возвращает `ubuntu:GNOME`, то это GNOME sHell и патч тут не работает (благодарим GNOME). А если она возвращает `Unity:Unity7:ubuntu`, то это Unity (установленная как мета-пакет `ubuntu-unity-desktop`) и патч тут тоже не работает. Я про это писал в ["Warranty disclaimer" в описании PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nrbrtx/+archive/ubuntu/xorg-hotkeys). К сожалению, ничем не могу помочь. Пишите в [спорт-лото](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/keyboard-layout-switching-problems-and-poll/2876/24).

Comment: @N0rbert да `Unity:Unity7:ubuntu`, жаль(